# JQuery not getting included in PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I am trying to use jquery with phantomjs. I tried a standalone example and it worked fine. Here is what I did:

```js
  var page = require('webpage').create();
  page.open("http://www.phantomjs.org", function(status) {

    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
      console.log("message recvd: " + msg);
    };

    var result;

    page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
      console.log("loading jquery");
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log("$(\"title\").text() -> " + $("title").text());
      });
    }, 1000);
 }
```

Here is the output I got:

```
loading jquery
message recvd: $("title").text() -> PhantomJS | PhantomJS
```

In the above code snippet, I have used setTimeout() on evaluate function because includeJs() would execute asynchronously and need some time to load jquery. If I do not use setTimeout() or use a small value for timeout, it doesn't work.

However, when I try the same code in my application it doesn't work. Here is what I have:

```js
var baseSetup = function(guid, page, config, request, response) {
  /* enable the console output inside the callback functions */
  page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(guid + ": console msg: " + msg);
  };

  /* used for ignoring potential alert messages when evaluating js code */
  page.onAlert = function (msg) {
    console.log(guid + " (alert): alert msg: " + msg);
  };

  /* suppress the error messages */
  page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
    if (trace && trace.length) {
      msgStack.push('TRACE:');
      trace.forEach(function(t) {
        msgStack.push(' -> ' +
        t.file +
        ': ' +
        t.line +
        (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function + '")' : ''));
      });
    }
    console.error(guid + ": " + msgStack.join('\n'));
  };
}

module.exports = function extractionDriver(responseFromUrl, responseToUser, page, request) {
  console.log(page.customHeaders['guid'] + ": extractionDriver, status = " + responseFromUrl.status);

  if(page.isLocalFile || responseFromUrl.status !== 0)
  {
    var viewportStr = page.customHeaders['viewportStr'];
    console.log(page.customHeaders['guid'] + ": Setting viewport size: " + viewportStr);
    var viewportObj = parseViewport(viewportStr);
    page.viewport = viewportObj;

    page.evaluate(function(w,h) {
      document.body.style.width = w + "px";
      document.body.style.height = h + "px";
    }, viewportObj.width, viewportObj.height);

    page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
      console.log("loading jquery");
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log("$(\"title\").text() -> " + $("title").text());
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

And this is what I see when I run my application:

```
    d8db6045-a0e8-11e4-a619-6949593d958d: ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
TRACE:
-> phantomjs://webpage.evaluate(): 3
-> phantomjs://webpage.evaluate(): 4
-> phantomjs://webpage.evaluate(): 4
```

The log line "loading jquery" is never printed and jquery is never loaded.

I have tried wrapping up the evaluate() function inside the callback of includeJs() but that didn't work either (no console log printed).

What could be going wrong here? Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is why `page.includeJs` has a callback, so you can put the code that depends on jQuery in there. The callback is called when the referenced JavaScript is already loaded. Welcome to another level on the road to the callback hell.

I experienced one time though that this didn't work for some reason. The workaround was to set a global variable in the `includeJs` callback and use [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait for the global variable to be set outside of the `includeJs` callback.

```
var _loadIndicator = false;
page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
  _loadIndicator = true;
});

waitFor(function check() {
  return _loadIndicator;
}, function onReady() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log("$(\"title\").text() -> " + $("title").text());
  });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: this is if you want to get it remotely...what if its already on your server and you just want to include the jquery .min fiile...you would use injectJs... but its still not working for me

Comment: @Carine I don't know what you mean by "server", but `page.injectJs` is only usable when the file is reachable through a file path. If it is not, then it must be reachable through a URI in which case `page.includeJs` must be used.

Comment: Yes, I know that.. but even though I have 

    page.injectJs('jquery.min.js'), i still get the error "Can't find variable: $"

Comment: @Carine No idea. You can ask a question. Maybe somebody has the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just have troubles with this, but my mistake was that, i tried `phantom.injectJs`, not `page.injectJs` (jerk). And then, if `status` is `success`, put

```
page.injectJs('lib/jquery.min.js');
```

and try

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    console.log($("body").length);
});
```